# Untracked files on gitbash

Tags: git, github, repository

Apparently I did `git init` before starting on my current git repository, im unsure on how to remove all the untracked files without deleting it permanetly from my computer or deleting my current repository on github.I suspect that `/c/Users/A/.git` is the issue, because basically most files on my computer is listed as untracked:

```
A@LAPTOP ~ (main)
$ find $HOME -type d -name .git
/c/Users/A/.git   #I WANT TO DELETE THIS
find: ‘/c/Users/A/AppData/Local/Temp/msdtadmin’: Permission denied
/c/Users/A/Desktop/Test/Project/GIT/.git # I DO NOT WANT TO DELETE THIS
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `.git` folder in the wrong place. You can rename it to anything not `.git` – it won't have any effect on other files. If you still need it, you can rename it back:

```
mv .git _.git_backup
```

If you made a mistake, the operation is reversible:

```
mv _.git_backup .git
```

---

If you have the `.git` directory in the wrong location and already worked on it, it is best to move it somewhere else to prevent any accidents (switching branches, losing worktree changes, etc.).

Create a new empty folder somewhere on your computer, e.g. `/tmp/recovery` and copy your `.git` folder there. Then switch to the directory and perform a `git status`. Does its output match your expectations? It probably will tell you about lots of "deleted in the worktree" files. If that's the case, do `git checkout HEAD -- .` **in your new *empty* directory**.

This will restore the files that are tracked in the Git repository. Check again your directory to match your expectations. Maybe you can manage to go from there. If not, let us know which files are available in the new directory and what you expect instead (edit your question and add this information to it).

In the end, *rename* the original `.git` directory in your home folder (rename, not remove. renaming allows you to undo the operation).

Comment: Does this command rename the first .git folder and not the second?

Comment: It renames the `.git` folder in your current working directory. If you `cd` into `/c/Users/A` it will rename that folder. If you `cd` into your `…/Desktop/Test/Project/GIT` folder, it will rename that one.

Comment: It won't let me cd to that path apparently. It gives me error: bash: cd : too many arguments. What is the correct syntax? (Im new to gitbash)

Comment: It should work. Does your path contain whitespace by any chance? If so, you have to quote it: `cd '/c/Users/My User Name'`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I can't seem to get this to work for some reason.

Comment: @Andycode "not working" or "can't get it to work" are very bad problem descriptions. What command are you running what error do you get (if any)? I/we cannot see your screen and don't know what you see.

Comment: Apparently I do not want to delete the first .git as mentioned, since the R script im working on is in a folder that builds on that .git repository. The last .git mentioned in my question is from earlier work and not related to what im doing. So the issue is that i did a git init for everything within 'c/Users/A'... i just want to remove the untracked files so that i can git add. only the changes im doing. So how do I remove untracked files without permanently deleting them from my computer?

Comment: I found this  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484800/entire-computer-in-git-status-untracked-files ) that addresses the issue, but the problem is that someone have already made changes in another branch in the git repository. Will this solution delete everything done on another branch as well?

Comment: @Andycode I have updated my answer. Can you recheck if that helps?